# Has_many through: association for category_sizes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a clothing store. I have Categories that have Sizes. A womens shirt (Category) might have XS, S, M, Large. A mens shirt can have XS, S, M, L. Shoes can have 4-16 and so on.

I have created a `has_many through: association` that connects the `Category` table with `Sizes` table by a `Cateogry_Sizes` table.

When an admin creates a Category, they should select all the Sizes that the Category will need.

**How can I select the Sizes in the below view?**

The current code is incorrect. In the console, when I go to `category.sizes`, I just get an empty array.

View:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
                    <%= simple_form_for(@category) do |f| %>
                      <div class="form-inputs">
                        <%= f.input :name %>
              <%= f.select(:sizes, Size.all.map {|s| [s.title, s.id]}, :multiple => true) %>
              <%= f.collection_select :parent_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, {prompt: "Select Parrent ID If Applicable"},include_blank: true %>
              <div class="form-actions"><%= f.button :submit %></div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry
    has_many :items
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  has_many :category_sizes
  has_many :sizes, through: :category_sizes
end
```

Size model:

```
class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 15 }
    validates :title, uniqueness: true

  has_many :category_sizes
  has_many :categories, through: :category_sizes
end
```

Category_size model:

```
class CategorySize < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :size
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150920013947) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "ancestry"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "categories", ["ancestry"], name: "index_categories_on_ancestry"

  create_table "category_sizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "size_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "category_sizes", ["category_id"], name: "index_category_sizes_on_category_id"
  add_index "category_sizes", ["size_id"], name: "index_category_sizes_on_size_id"

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "items", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_items_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "items", ["user_id"], name: "index_items_on_user_id"

  create_table "sizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
  end

  add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",               default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",           default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.string   ">"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.text     "description"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

Controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category,   only: [:show]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy, :index, :edit, :show]

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
    @tags = Item.where(category_id: @category.id).tag_counts_on(:tags)
    if params[:tag]
      @items = Item.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @items = Item.where(category_id: @category.id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    if @category.save
      redirect_to @category
      flash[:success] = "You have created a new category"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Your category didn't save"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def update
    @Cateogry = Category.find(params[:id])
    if @Cateogry.update(category_params)
       redirect_to @Cateogry
       flash[:success] = 'Category was successfully updated.'
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Category.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Category deleted"
    redirect_to categories_path
  end

  private

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :parent_id)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)
    end

end
```

Here is what happens when in console:

```
2.1.2 :026 > c = Category.last
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  ORDER BY "categories"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Category id: 57, name: "Test20", ancestry: "20", created_at: "2015-09-23 12:35:14", updated_at: "2015-09-23 12:35:14">
2.1.2 :027 > c.sizes
  Size Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sizes".* FROM "sizes" INNER JOIN "category_sizes" ON "sizes"."id" = "category_sizes"."size_id" WHERE "category_sizes"."category_id" = ?  [["category_id", 57]]
```

Here is what happens on form submit in server log:

```
Started POST "/categories" for ::1 at 2015-09-23 22:37:28 +1000
Processing by CategoriesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4pMZ9PUr5yTSCNRiQeATljZsOIDeQCwhQPy9djEbAmejntpb8/DkK20JrMUeZkStsB5UU6YhbtExGwDKs7tT2Q==", "category"=>{"name"=>"test21", "sizes"=>"6", "parent_id"=>"20"}, "commit"=>"Create Category"}
Unpermitted parameter: sizes
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 20]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "categories" ("name", "ancestry", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "test21"], ["ancestry", "20"], ["created_at", "2015-09-23 12:37:28.927360"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-23 12:37:28.927360"]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/categories/58
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)


Started GET "/categories/58" for ::1 at 2015-09-23 22:37:28 +1000
Processing by CategoriesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"58"}
```

Comment: In the form you can see all the available sizes and you can chose them and submit the form? Can you also show the category_controller?

Comment: @EgonWilzer Yeah i just posted the controller. Yes at the moment i can see the sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow the sizes in the params of the controller like this:

```
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :parent_id, size_ids: [])
    end
```

In your form you should probably change:

```
<%= f.select(:sizes, Size.all.map {|s| [s.title, s.id]}, :multiple => true) %>
```

to

```
<%= f.association :sizes %>
```

Simple form should then do the magic. See also: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations for more information.

Comment: Thanks I just tried that and created a new category with 1 size selected. I have posted the results when i run category.sizes

Comment: I just changed it from `sizes` to `size_ids`. Have you tried with that? Can you see what happens in the server console on form submit? Are there any unpermitted parameter messages?

Comment: Yep i just posted the server log from form submit so you can see. Thank heaps.

Comment: YES THAT WORKED. OMG thank you so much. I've worked on it for many many hours. I just realised if 2 categories have the same size name like Womens Shirt will have same sizes as Mens shirt , im going to have to create another size. I will have duplicates of the same named sizes.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, I felt it apt to highlight that [you may be able to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) to make this work in its current form. It works very similarly to `has_many :through` except it doesn't have a join model:

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :sizes
end

#app/models/size.rb
class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

This will mean you'll have to drop your `category_sizes` table and replace it with `categories_sizes` with `category_id | size_id` columns:

[image]

This is *only* recommended if you don't want to include any further information in your join model. For example, if you wanted to include stock levels or something, the join model of `has_many :through` would be vital; not as you have it now.

It will also allow you to call:

```
@category = Category.find params[:id]
@category.sizes #-> collection of sizes for category.
```

--

**Form**

HABTM also would make the form much simpler:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@category) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.collection_select :sizes, Size.all, :id, :name, { multiple: true } %>
    <%= f.collection_select :parent_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, {prompt: "Select Parent ID If Applicable"},include_blank: true %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def create
       @category = Category.new category_params
   end

   private

   def category_params
       params.require(:category).permit(:etc, :etc, :sizes)
   end
end
```